# Just like DataBinding classes. How to generate classes in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-databinding

We can create the DataBinding class in the Android studio. The View references (with name as corresponding view id) are created automatically.
I would like to know how to create this kind of feature.
Thank you

Do you think this is done with Dagger (compile-time dependency injection)?

Comment: something like this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/8574679-annotation-processing-supercharge-your-development

Comment: Thank you very much @Blundell , For sating my curiosity.